# How to use mat-calendar with reactive forms?

Tags: angular

I want to use a calendar component without an `input` in a reactive form.

I found the component `mat-calendar` and tried this:

```html
<mat-calendar formControlName="appointment"></mat-calendar>
```

The corresponding TypeScript file has this:

```js
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ appointment: [''] });
```

But an error was shown:

```
ERROR Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'appointment'
```

Comment: You need to add more details to your question. What does your FormGroup look like? **Is** there a formcontrol with name `appointment` ?

Comment: @prettyfly, I updated the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to use this as a datepicker for a form, then using the [Material datepicker is a better option](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview#connecting-a-datepicker-to-an-input), and it supports reactive form controls out of the box.

However, if you want a static calendar (i.e always visible), and just need to update your form when a user selects a value, then you can listen to it's change event, and set your form value yourself.

`<mat-calendar [selected]="form.get('appointment').value" (selectedChange)="updateFormDate($event)"></mat-calendar>`

```
updateFormDate(value: any) {
    this.form.get('appointment').setValue(value);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

@prettyfly's answer is spot-on. I just wanted to add that the reason it's not working is that mat-calendar as a component doesn't implement the ControlValueAccessor, which is the interface necessary for FormControls to work.

If you wanted to encapsulate things better, you could take @prettyfly's solution and wrap it in a custom component and implement ControlValueAccessor on it. Only then could you use it the way you described.

Answer (score 0):

**my-component.component.html**

```
<mat-calendar [(selected)]="selected"></mat-calendar>
```

**my-component.component.ts**

```
get selected(): Moment | undefined {
    return this.form?.get('appointment')?.value;
}

set selected(value: Moment | undefined) {
    this.form?.get('appointment')?.setValue(value);
}
```